# Problems with selecting submenus in a web page in android web browsers

Tags: browser, menu

When selecting a web page menu (e.g. in Firefox), the sub menu sometimes shows but you can't select anything out of it. The sub menu closes automatically after a short while. This behaviour is also present in Chrome. I have seen this on android 4 and 5 for certain and read a lot of others having the same problem but so far no solution.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?